# How to send form information (including files) to an e-mail?

Tags: php, jquery, post, upload

```
<?php

if ($_POST['name'] && $_POST['info']) {
  $message = "";
  $message .= "Nimi:\n" . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "E-mail:\n" . $_POST['mail'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "Phone:\n" . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
  $message .= "File:\n" . $_POST['file'] . "\n\n"; // probably wrong
  $message .= "Message:\n" . $_POST['info'] . "\n\n";

  mail("me@me.me", "blablabla (example.com)", $message, "From: example.com <me@me.me>");
}
```

I am getting all the other values with jquery-ajax (taking the val() from the textareas and posting them to the process.php file), but how do I pass on a file and use it in the mail function?

I had a look at some plugins, but I would prefer adding a little something to the code I already have, it can't be that hard...

```
$("input.submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $(".feedback textarea.name").val();
  var mail = $(".feedback textarea.mail").val();
  var phone = $("feedback textarea.phone").val();
  var file = $("feedback input.file").val(); //probably wrong
  var info = $(".feedback textarea.info").val();

  if (name && mail && info) {
    var data = {name: name, mail: mail, phone: phone, file: file, info: info};

    $.post("process.php", data, function() {
      $("textarea, input").val("");
        alert("thank you for submitting");
    });
  }
  else {
    alert("something is missing");
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: I would suggest using phpmailer package to add files into your email, writing it yourself ain't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to upload the file via AJAX? Here is a good [discussion on how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Once you uploaded your file, if you want to put the content of the file into your email then you'll need parse the file from the HTTPRequest. If you want to add the file as an attachment, here's a [good reference](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script) on how that can be done